# _setViewDelegate unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, ios6

I am getting this exception:

2012-10-11 14:27:05.039 SunriseAlarm[2297:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PickerViewController _setViewDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e56fff0'

I have this code in the appDelegate.m file

PickerViewController *pvc = [[PickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PickerView" bundle:nil];

self.window.rootViewController = pvc;

I have already set the class of the nib to the custom class and it is not UIViewController. Please see image below.

[image: Here is the image of XCode window]

Please let me know what do you think I am doing wrong.

Thank You,

Venkat Rao

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You did set PickerViewController  class for UIView, it's not correct, return back and set PickerViewController for File's owner